# QGridLayout labels are writing on eachother

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel, qgridlayout

[here you can find the screenshoot of my labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rYEj.jpg) I have two labels in my Qt project and I want to placed them into a frame. Here is the sample of my code. All labels are writing on eachother. Is there any idea?

```
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(frame);
QLabel *mean_300 = new QLabel(frame);
mean_300->setText("300gram ortalama :");
QLabel *mean_350 = new QLabel(frame);
mean_350->setText("350 gram ortalama : ");
layout->addWidget(mean_300,1,2);
layout->addWidget(mean_350,1,3);
```

Comment: It looks like your "frame" contains more widgets than you shown here. Please provide the complete code.

Comment: If I use the code shown as the basis of a [mcve] then I can't repro. (Suse Linux + Qt5.15.0).

Comment: No my frame contains only those labels.